# flask-sock doesn't send/receive messages on Cloud Run

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-run, cloud-run-emulator

If I clone Miguel Grinberg's [flask-sock](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-sock) and run `examples/clock.py` I get a `templates/clock.html` which receives time updates every second over a web socket.

If I then put a `dockerfile` into the project and install the dependencies I can get a deployment onto Cloud Run but `clock.html` doesn't receive the messages.  I can see the websocket is up using Chrome's dev tools.  If I hit the stop button on the page then it logs [Stopped] which implies it received the `close` event over the websocket.

I'm using VSCode with the Cloud Code extension to deploy to Cloud Run.  I get the same behaviour on the the emulator.  I've removed `EXEC` from the gunicorn line and taken the Python version down to 3.9.6 from 3.10-alpine in desperation.  I've modified `clock.html` to use `wss` rather than `ws`.

dockerfile:

```
# Python image to use.
FROM python:3.9.6

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy the requirements file used for dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the working directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Run app.py when the container launches
# ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV GEVENT_SUPPORT=True
CMD gunicorn -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 --chdir examples clock:app

#CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app
```